# New outbound SSH hangs after old SSH session is terminated

Tags: networking, router, ssh

I have a home server that I SSH into from my laptop. I'm having an issue where:

1. I SSH into the server, and it works fine
2. I put my laptop to sleep for whatever reason
3. Upon waking, the SSH connection has disconnected. When I try to reconnect to the server, the SSH connection hangs until timeout

I've verified the SSH requests are not getting to the server, but I'm not sure if the issue is with my laptop or the router. I *think* it's the router because I can fix the hanging issue by restarting the router, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions for debugging this?

SSH print out for failed connection:

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/username/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for 10.0.0.239
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.239 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.239 [10.0.0.239] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address 10.0.0.239 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.239 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Extra detail: if you look up SSH connections that hang at `set_sock_tos`, you'll find suggestions to add `-o IPQoS=none` to the SSH request. I tried this and it doesn't fix the issue.